# How can I prevent a task to be moved from a CPU to another?

Tags: c, concurrency, linux-kernel

I am currently building a Kernel module and I want to face SMP issues in a quite-optimal way.

Currently, I have a set of objects and each one is bound to a particular CPU. The following code illustrates this :

```c
struct my_object {
    int a_field;
};

struct my_object cpu_object[NR_CPUS];
/*
 * cpu_object[i] is "bound" to CPU number "i" !
 */
```

A simple call to `smp_processor_id()` will then give me the processor on which the current code is running. So if I have a function `foo` that does some work using the CPU-bound objects described above, it might look like :

```c
void foo()
{
    int cpu = smp_processor_id();
    do_some_work_with(cpu_object[cpu]);
}
```

The question is : How to guarantee that

1. There is no CPU switch between `cpu` assignment and `do_some_work_with` ?
2. `do_some_work_with()` will only run on `cpu` ?

At the time, the solution I think about is :

1. Disable preemption using a spinlock
2. Get the CPU with `smp_processor_id`
3. Set the processor affinity of the current task to make it stick with the current CPU
4. Enable preemption again, releasing the lock
5. Do the work `do_some_work_with()`
6. Reset the affinity to its previous state

To me it is quite barbarian and I was wondering if there was smarter and lighter way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT** :
As stated in the comments, I edit to explain why I feel I need such features.
I have to perform on-the-fly encryption on a *filesystem* level.
To do so, I will use the Kernel built-in cryptographic support (`struct crypto_tfm` and friends). Here is the original issue...

On multi-core machines, it is possible to perform multiple R/W operations at the same time. The common fs layer does it and does it well. But, here I come and mess things up :

- A `struct crypto_tfm`-like object is in charge for the ciphering operation
- A same transform object cannot be used at the same time since some parameters would be altered (private key and initialization vector) and screw all the process
- A naive solution as described below is completely out of the question due to the complex cipher allocation system built in crypto.

  1. Allocate the `crypto_tfm` transformation
  2. Perform the ciphering operation
  3. Free the transformation object
- A classic scheme where only one transform is available prevents multiple concurrent R/W operations since one task would have to wait for another to release the lock held to protect the transform object.

For these reasons, I need to deal with multiple transformation objects. I must find an efficient scheme that allows concurrent R/W. I feel my "Y" here is "the solution that is simple, neat ... and wrong".
Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

*Note* : If I use a solution like the one I gave in the original question, I would limit it to very short sections to avoid heavy impact on CPU load balancing.

Comment: Why do you see a need to exercise this level of control?  Does your module have problems if you don't?

Comment: I feel quite strongly that your overall approach is wrong. Forcing the kernel to run a kernel thread on a particular CPU is definitely something not right. I do believe the method you describe would work, but it seems very wrong.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I have the same feeling ... But I cannot figure out how to guarantee smooth SMP within the tasks I need to run. I could edit to explain you the context that lead me consider this kind of horrible things

Comment: It may help - as I feel this is a typical XY question - you thin the right solution is to do Y to solve X, so you ask how to do Y.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I edited, you should have the "X" now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on your edited question, I have to say that I think your solution is wrong.

The right thing to do is to have a "per operation" `crypto_tfm`, that follows that operation across CPU's. Using the "current CPU" is not the right thing here. [What happens if the this is running on a system with hot-swappable CPUs, and someone disconnects the CPU your task is running on - and never puts one back in it's place?]

If it's costly to allocate a `crypto_tfm` per operation, then you have to find some way to avoid allocating/freeing the objects - have a pool of them and assign an available to the current operation, and when the operation is complete, put it back into the available list again.

Comment: What are the available policies when there is no object ready to use, apart from the two obvious ones (allocate a new object or simply wait for an existing one to become available) ? From what I read so far, a CPU cannot be hot-unplugged if a task cannot be moved to another one

Comment: Those are the only two I can think of. Well, with a third "hybrid" one, I suppose, based on `if (num_allocated_crypt_tfm < max_allocated_crypt_tfm) allocate_new_crypt_tfm(); else wait_for_available_crypt_tfm();` - that way, you can keep a limit on how many `crypt_tfm` there are, but at the same time not have to allocate a lot of them to start with.